# Weird behavior in selenium js wait

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, async-await

I'm using this code to wait for an element.

```
    const seconds = 2 * 1000;
    await browser.wait(until.elementLocated(byElement), seconds)
    .then(() => {
      const element = browser.findElement(args.field);
      browser.wait(until.elementIsVisible(element, seconds))
    })
```

My question is: Is this only going to wait for 2 seconds? Or 2 seconds + 2 seconds more for each for each element (because of the nested wait)?

Comment: This will wait only 2 as currently written. If you return the promise inside your `.then`, eg: `return browser.wait(...)`, then it will wait 2 + each 2. An `await` call will not finish until it's promise has resolved completely, including any chained `.then`s. Also, you may have misplaced a parenthesis on your second `wait` call.

Comment: suggest to add `return` at the begining of second wait